# Cannot safely delete LPTSTR allocation

Tags: c++, winapi

Consider:

```
CCustomDateTime::CCustomDateTime()
{
    LPTSTR result = new TCHAR[1024];
    time_t _currentTime_t = time(0);
    tm now;

    localtime_s(&now, &_currentTime_t);
    _tasctime_s(result, _tcslen(result), &now);

    _currentTime = result;
    delete[] result; // Error occurs here
}


CCustomDateTime::~CCustomDateTime()
{

}

__int64 CCustomDateTime::CurrentTimeAsInt64()
{
    return _currentTime_t;
}

LPTSTR CCustomDateTime::CurrentTimeAsString()
{
    return _currentTime;
}
```

I am unable to figure out the safest place to call `delete[]` on `result`.

If `delete[]` is ignored everything is fine, but otherwise an error occurs:

> HEAP CORUPTION DETECTED at line delete[]

Comment: Which error? Please be specific

Comment: HEAP CORUPTION DETECTED at line delete[]

Comment: You are passing the "length" of uninitialised memory with `_tcslen(result)`. Should you be passing `1024`?

Comment: what should be done here

Comment: `_tasctime_s(result, 1024, &now);`?

Comment: Please don't use TCHAR and related functions unless you explicitly want to support WIndows 98. There's no other reason to resort to this madness.

Comment: @rubenvb so WCHAR is sufficient if i target winxp and above

Comment: @Rahul: Just use `wchar_t`, yes.

Comment: @rubenvb thank you. but where to delete[] the result after assigning result to _currentTime

Comment: Also, if you're using C++, use a std::wstring or other RAII classes to magically make your problem go away.

Comment: I re-tagged your question to remove the C tag. Your are writing C++ code, you are not writing C code. Contrary to seemingly popular belief, these are in fact two different languages.

Comment: And I also restored the original code from the question, with all the original mistakes. Please don't remove your mistakes and so make the question be a running target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code that I can see:

1. You don't check any of the function calls for errors. Don't ignore the return value. Use it to check for errors.
2. The second argument to `_tasctime_s` is the number of elements in the buffer provided. In other words, `1024`. But you pass `_tcslen(result)` which is the length of the null-terminated string. Not only is that the wrong value, but `result` is at that point not initialised, so your code has undefined behaviour.
3. You assign a value to `_currentTime`, and then immediately delete that memory. So, `_currentTime` is a stale pointer. Any attempt to read from that memory is yet more undefined behaviour.

I don't want to tell you what your code should be, because you have only given us a tiny window into what you are trying to achieve. Dynamically allocating a fixed length array seems pointless. You may as well use automatically allocated storage. Of course, if you do want to return the memory to the caller, then dynamic allocation makes sense, but in that case then surely the caller would be responsible for calling `delete[]`. Since this code is clearly C++ I have to wonder why you are using raw memory allocation. Why not use standard library classes like `std::string`?

Looking at your update to the question, you could deallocate the memory in the destructor of your class. Personally though, I would recommend learning about the standard library classes that will greatly simplify your code.

Comment: then where to delete[] the result

Comment: That would depend entirely upon the bigger picture that you have not shown us, and  I'm just attempting to answer the question that you asked. But certainly you'll want to make sure you have finished using the memory before deallocating it. A far better idea will be to use standard library classes whose lifetime is manage automatically.

Answer (score 2):

`_tcslen(result)` is not doing what you think it is.
change

```
_tasctime_s(result, _tcslen(result), &now);
```

to

```
_tasctime_s(result, 1024, &now);
```

Answer (score 1):

`_tcslen` maps to `strlen` or `wcslen` depending on whether you are using ANSI or Unicode, respectively.

Both these functions return the *length* of a *string*, not the *size* of the *buffer*.  In other words, they take a pointer to the first character of a string and continuously increment the pointer in search of a null terminator.

Calling these functions on an uninitialized buffer is undefined behavior because there's a very good chance that the pointer will get incremented out of the array bounds and elsewhere into the process' memory.

Comment: Pedantry corner. It is not UB because of likelihood of buffer overrun. It is UB because the buffer is not initialized to be null terminated. Likelihood of any outcome is irrelevant.